# IF Session data exists, output in view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

So I'm trying to output a session's variable value into a view (only if it exists). But I can't seem to get it to work. No error. Nothing. What am I missing? Thought I had this down packed by now - guess not...

In controller...FYI, $data is assigned to the view (i.e. `$this -> load -> view('view', $data);`

```
$data['campaign_name'] = $this -> session -> userdata('campaign_name');
```

Here's my php snippet in the view that I'm trying to output. So in short, if the session exists, output it. If not, do nothing.

```
<input type="text" name="campaign_name" class="wizardInput nameField" value="<? if (isset($campaign_name)) ;?> ">
```

Anyone?

**EDIT** Okay, I should have mentioned that i'm trying to output the session value into a FORM value. Modified view code above. The form submits as though the value is there - and even sends the value along. However, it's not visible in the text input...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can easly do this in your view:

```
if($this->session->userdata('campaign_name')){
 // do somenthing cause it exist
}
```

then if you want to make session data as the value of an input do this:

```
<input type="text" name="campaign_name" class="wizardInput nameField" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('campaign_name') ?>">
```

you **don't need to control if session userdata exist** cause if it not exist it doesn't prints anything, cause `userdata()` method returns `false` !

Then you don't need to pass session data trough the `$data[] array`, cause session data can be retrieved from anywhere (model/controllers/views/hooks/libraries/helpers and so on)

Comment: Is this not the dirty way? I thought this was looked down upon. No?
Check out my edit above...the input value is reading the session value, but it's visible for some reason...what the...

Comment: Should also mention, I want to INSERT the sessions value into the Text Input Value.

Comment: if you want to make input hidden you should use  **type="hidden"** then

Comment: Awesome. Say I have a default value already in the text input. What then? If session exists, it should override...

Comment: Input doesn't need to be hidden. This is just used if a user goes "back" to the preview page in the ajax wizard I'm creating. Last step in wizard I send to database and kill this userdata.

Comment: userdata() returns value or false , so if exist is printed else nothing is printed

Comment: if you need more explanations read the guide it is so simple and well done :)

Comment: glad to have been helpfull to you!