# CodeIgniter - Check if Session variable exist

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, input

In CodeIgniter, checking if an input exists is easy.

Rather than using

```
$something = isset($_POST['something']) ? $_POST['something'] : NULL;
```

You can simply do:

```
$something = $this->input->post('something');
```

---

My question is, is it the same with session?

```
$something = isset($_SESSION['something']) ? $_SESSION['something'] : NULL;
```

the same with

```
$something = $this->session->something;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF Session data exists, output in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478836/if-session-data-exists-output-in-view)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556194/codeigniter-checking-session-variable-is-already-set-or-not-when-clicking-each-l

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter-Checking session variable is already set or not when clicking each link or reloading page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556194/codeigniter-checking-session-variable-is-already-set-or-not-when-clicking-each-l)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$this->session->something` will work just fine.

Just remember to load the library. And read the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) if you like:

Answer (score 1):

Check whether session variable is set or not using `$this->session->has_userdata('variable');` so try like this..

```
$something = $this->session->has_userdata('something')? $this->session->userdata('something') : NULL;
```

> if session variable is not set then `$something` has `NULL` value
>   otherwise it has session value.

For more see [codeigniter session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)